# Forbid null (or return default value) in JavaFX SimpleObjectProperty

Tags: java, javafx, properties, javafx-2

I have a class with a `SimpleObjectProperty<SomeFunctionalInterface>` member. I don't want to clutter my code with any null checks on its value; instead I have a default implementation of `SomeFunctionalInterface`, the only method of which is simply empty. At the present, I assign this default value as the initial value of the property, and also have a change listener on the property which sets the value of the property back to the default implementation if anyone attempts to set its value to null. This, however, feels a bit clunky, and setting a thing's value from inside its change listener makes me feel dirty.

Short of creating my own class extending `SimpleObjectProperty`, are there any ways of getting an object property to return some predefined  default value if its current value is `null`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could expose a non-null binding to the property:

```
public class SomeBean {

    private final ObjectProperty<SomeFunctionalInterface> value = new SimpleObjectProperty<>();

    private final SomeFunctionalInterface defaultValue = () -> {} ;

    private final Binding<SomeFunctionalInterface> nonNullBinding = Bindings.createObjectBinding(() -> {
        SomeFunctionalInterface val = value.get();
        return val == null ? defaultValue : val ;
    }, property);

    public final Binding<SomeFunctionalInterface> valueProperty() {
        return nonNullBinding ;
    }

    public final SomeFunctionalInterface getValue() {
        return valueProperty().getValue();
    }

    public final void setValue(SomeFunctionalInterface value) {
        valueProperty.set(value);
    }

    // ...
}
```

This won't work for all use cases, but may suffice for what you need.